# Way to gather statistical info on a .NET assembly's size

Tags: .net, profiling

I've built an assembly that's significantly larger than I'd expect it to be--given the code and resources that went into it, I'd expect it to come out at around 5 MB, but its size turns out to be 35 MB instead!

If my code was running slowly, I could run it through a profiler and get statistical information about where it's spending all that time.  Is there any equivalent tool that will tell me what's taking up so much space?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use an decompiler like [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). As far as I know it does not show you the size of the content. You would need to extract the resources to get the size. But it would allow you to see content that you don't expect to be included.

Another tool could be dumpbin. But I haven't used it much, however it should work with .Net assembly's. You can find some quick info about it [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25350)